# Vizualize Lighting & Solar 3d view in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, footprint

I generated an analysis and created an element called analisys result, where it shows me the analysis, I want to save that view and display it in forge viewer, but when I display the view in forge viewer it doesn't show me the analysis, does anyone know how to do it?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The Autodesk Platform Services APS (formerly Forge) Viewer is a generic tool for all types of CAD models, generated from all kinds of different seed files. The analysis result you refer to comes from a domain-specific CAD modeller (BIM? Revit?) and probably cannot be automatically transferred to the completely generic APS viewer.

Comment: Hello, the solar analysis is done by the Insight revit plugin, it takes you to a website that, as I have seen, has a forge viewer where the analyzes are displayed, which is insight360

Answer (score 0):

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

Please check the above link for the supported formats.
Analysis information is shown only if that data is part of the metadata of the seed file.